# Target tag in form does not work

Tags: html

I have a simple search box form and I want the results to open in a new window using target="_top". I have tried everything and searched everywhere but no matter what I try, it just doesn't work. I use target="_top" in lots of regular links on my site with no problem. I'm using Firefox 5.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `target="_blank"` to open it in a new window.

Answer (score 4):

The following values, which begin with an underscore can be used for the target of a hyperlink:

```
_blank  Renders the content in a new window without frames.
_parent Renders the content in the immediate frameset parent.
_self   Renders the content in the frame with focus.
_top    Renders the content in the full window without frames.

For your case you should use <a href="" target="_blank">my link</a>
```

Comment: I had already tried all of that but they didn't work. I did however find the solution. I used this: form method="get" target="searchstring" which is from this:input type="Text" name="searchstring". Thanks